# Kivy change attributes of dynamically created buttons

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is there any way to access dynamically created buttons in PageLayout in python file so that after i click button it will change text?

```
{
    "animals": {
        "kot": "cat",
        "pies": "dog",
        "krowa": "cow"
    },
    "food": {
        "jajko": "egg",
        "szynka": "ham",
        "mleko": "milk"
    }
}
```

py.file

```
class CardGame(Screen):
    page = ObjectProperty(None)
    def cards(self):
        with open('data.json') as file:
            words = json.load(file)
            name = self.manager.get_screen('before_game').ids.spinner.text
            for key in words[name]:
                self.ids.page.add_widget(Button(text=str(key)))
```

kv.file

```
<CardGame>:
    page:page
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:'back'
                on_press:root.back()
        PageLayout:
            border:100        <<<<<< Here it creates in this case 3 buttons
            id:page
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:'left'
            Button:
                text:'right'


<RootWidget>:

    LoginScreen:
        name:'login_screen'
    SignUpScreen:
        name:'sign_up'

    LoginSuccesfull:
        name:'login_succesfull'
    ForgotPassword:
        name:'forgot_password'
    CardGame:
        name:'card_game'
        on_pre_enter:self.cards()
        on_leave:self.remove_buttons()
    NewWord:
        name:'new_word'
        on_enter:self.spiner()
    BeforeGame:
        name:'before_game'
        on_enter:self.spiner()
        on_leave:self.clear_spinner()
    Test:
        name:'test'
        on_pre_enter:self.testujemy()
```

After choosing folder name for example food it creates new Screen with PageLayout where it creates as many buttons as many items i have in my dict.
My question is, is there any way that i can access those buttons so after i click on it it will change their  text to dict.value so for example from Button with text = 'cow' after clickking it will change to 'krowa'

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot add ids to new widgets in the python file I suggest you create a dict to store all of the newly created buttons. For example create a dict called self.buttons = {}. And then every time you create a new button in the 'for' loop do this:

```
for key in words[name]:
    button = Button(text=str(key))
    self.buttons[key] = button
    self.ids.page.add_widget(button)
```

Now that you have all of the widgets stored in the dict you can write a new function where you can access them by name and do whatever you want with them.
For example if you want to change the text you'll do:

```
def some_function(self):
    with open('data.json') as file:
        words = json.load(file)
        self.buttons['krowa'].text = words['krowa']
```

Let me know if this helps